# HTTP 503 – Service Unavailable – craft\web\ServiceUnavailableHttpException

Tags: error

I have a problem with my page after upload on server. Currently a enabled devMode and while loading it shows

> **HTTP 503 – Service Unavailable – craft\web\ServiceUnavailableHttpException**
>
> **whatmore**:
>
> vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php at line 386 – craft\web\Application::handleRequest(craft\web\Request)

web.log below:

> 2018-07-19 07:11:06 [80.55.43.241][-][72baf4994c2e29ee1f32982349aec971][info][yii\db\Connection::open] Opening DB connection: mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_database;port=3306;
>   2018-07-19 07:11:06 [80.55.43.241][-][72baf4994c2e29ee1f32982349aec971][profile begin][yii\db\Connection::open] Opening DB connection: mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_database;port=3306;
>   2018-07-19 07:11:06 [80.55.43.241][-][72baf4994c2e29ee1f32982349aec971][profile end][yii\db\Connection::open] Opening DB connection: mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_database;port=3306;
>   2018-07-19 07:11:06 [80.55.43.241][-][72baf4994c2e29ee1f32982349aec971][error][craft\db\Connection::open] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
>   2018-07-19 07:11:06 [80.55.43.241][-][72baf4994c2e29ee1f32982349aec971][error][craft\db\Connection::open] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
>   2018-07-19 07:11:06 [80.55.43.241][-][72baf4994c2e29ee1f32982349aec971][info][yii\web\Session::open] Session started
>   2018-07-19 07:11:06 [80.55.43.241][-][72baf4994c2e29ee1f32982349aec971][error][yii\web\HttpException:503] craft\web\ServiceUnavailableHttpException in /path/to/public_html/www/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php:507
>   Stack trace:
>
> 0 /home/cluster-sites/3/t/toolmach.co.uk/public_html/www/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(184): craft\web\Application->_processInstallRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
>
> 1 /home/cluster-sites/3/t/toolmach.co.uk/public_html/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
>
> 2 /home/cluster-sites/3/t/toolmach.co.uk/public_html/www/web/index.php(21): yii\base\Application->run()
>
> 3 {main}
>   2018-07-19 07:11:07 [80.55.43.241][-][72baf4994c2e29ee1f32982349aec971][trace][yii\base\View::renderFile] Rendering view file: /path/to/public_html/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/views/errorHandler/exception.php
>   2018-07-19 07:11:07 [80.55.43.241][-][72baf4994c2e29ee1f32982349aec971][trace][yii\base\View::renderFile] Rendering view file: /path/to/public_html/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/views/errorHandler/callStackItem.php
>   2018-07-19 07:11:07 [80.55.43.241][-][72baf4994c2e29ee1f32982349aec971][trace][yii\base\View::renderFile] Rendering view file: /path/to/public_html/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/views/errorHandler/callStackItem.php
>   2018-07-19 07:11:07 [80.55.43.241][-][72baf4994c2e29ee1f32982349aec971][trace][yii\base\View::renderFile] Rendering view file: /path/topublic_html/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/views/errorHandler/callStackItem.php
>   2018-07-19 07:11:07 [80.55.43.241][-][72baf4994c2e29ee1f32982349aec971][trace][yii\base\View::renderFile] Rendering view file: /path/topublic_html/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/views/errorHandler/callStackItem.php
>   2018-07-19 07:11:05 [80.55.43.241][-][72baf4994c2e29ee1f32982349aec971][info][application] $_GET = []
>
> $_POST = []
>
> $_FILES = []

Comment: Have you tried loading the Control Panel? A 503 is what gets served on a front-end request is the system is offline or there is a pending update. Loading the Control Panel should give you more info.

Comment: Actually from the logs, it looks like Craft doesn't think it's installed. So it you loaded the CP, you'll probably get the installer. That usually means something isn't correct in your `craft/config/db.php` file.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but the first place I'd look is your logs on your server. As an example, I'm running nginx on my server and the logs are located in `/var/log/nginx/`.

Comment: logs added above